# Unable to create managed bean DBUserMBean. The following problems were found: - Bean or property class (...) cannot be found

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to make a Java, and JSF project with a MySQL database using Hibernate and PrimeFaces.

Hibernate layer works good(basic CRUD works fine), but after I make basic GUI with Prime Faces and deploy project into Tomcat, server, it returns an error:

```
Unable to create managed bean DBUserMBean. The following problems were 
found: - Bean or property class 
com/hibernate/maven/Hibernate_APP/DBUserManagedBean for managed bean 
DBUserMBean cannot be found.
```

Here are all the files in my project:

**DBUser**

```
@Entity
public final class DBUser{
    private Long  id;
    private String kolumna1;
    private String kolumna2;
    private String kolumna3;
    private int  kolumna4;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
        strBuff.append("id :").append(id);
        strBuff.append("kolumna1 :").append(kolumna1);
        strBuff.append("kolumna2 :").append(kolumna2);
        strBuff.append("kolumna3 :").append(kolumna3);
        strBuff.append("kolumna4 :").append(kolumna4);
        return strBuff.toString();
    }
}
```

**DBUserManagedBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="DBUserManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class DBUserManagedBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DBUserManagedBean.class);
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String ERROR   = "error";

    private Long  id;
    private String kolumna1;
    private String kolumna2;
    private String kolumna3;
    private int  kolumna4;

    private String message;

    //getters and setters   

    public String getMessage() {
        StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
        strBuff.append("id :").append(id);
        strBuff.append("kolumna1 :").append(kolumna1);
        strBuff.append("kolumna2 :").append(kolumna2);
        strBuff.append("kolumna3 :").append(kolumna3);
        strBuff.append("kolumna4 :").append(kolumna4);
        this.setMessage(strBuff.toString());
        return this.message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    } 

    public String save() {
        String result = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        DBUser dbuser = new DBUser();

        dbuser.setKolumna1(this.getKolumna1());
        dbuser.setKolumna2(this.getKolumna2());
        dbuser.setKolumna3(this.getKolumna3());
        dbuser.setKolumna4(this.getKolumna4());

        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(dbuser);
            tx.commit();
            log.debug("New Record : " + dbuser + ", wasCommitted : " + tx.wasCommitted());
            result = SUCCESS;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
                result = ERROR;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
    }
    return result;
}

public List<DBUser> getDBUsers() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<DBUser>  dbuserList = session.createCriteria(DBUser.class).list();
    return dbuserList;
}

public void reset() {
    this.setKolumna1("");
    this.setKolumna2("");
    this.setKolumna3("");
    this.setKolumna4(kolumna4);
}

}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"

version="2.0">

<managed-bean>

    <managed-bean-name>DBUserMBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.hibernate.maven.Hibernate_APP.DBUserManagedBean</managed-   
bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>

</managed-bean>


<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>pages/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>pages/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>pages/error.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

<h:head><title>Hibernate_APP</title></h:head>
<body>
 <h:form>


     <table>
         <tr>
            <td><h:outputLabel for="kolumna1" value="kolumna1 :" /></td>
            <td><p:inputText id="kolumna1" value="#{DBUserManagedBean.kolumna1}"/></td>
         </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><h:outputLabel for="kolumna2" value="kolumna2 :" /></td>
            <td><p:inputText id="kolumna2" value="#{DBUserManagedBean.kolumna2}"/></td>
         </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><h:outputLabel for="kolumna3" value="kolumna3 :" /></td>
            <td><p:inputText id="kolumna3" value="#{DBUserManagedBean.kolumna3}"/></td>
         </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><h:outputLabel for="kolumna4" value="kolumna4 :" /></td>
            <td><p:inputText id="kolumna4" value="#{DBUserManagedBean.kolumna4}"/></td>
         </tr>



         <tr>
            <td><p:commandButton id="submit" value="Save" action="#   
{DBUserManagedBean.save}" ajax="false"/></td>
            <td><p:commandButton id="reset" value="Reset" action="#   
{DBUserManagedBean.reset}" ajax="false"/></td>

         </tr>
     </table>


 </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<h:head>
<title>Hibernate_APP</title>
</h:head>
<body>
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="Saved Record is #{DBUserMBean.message}"></h:outputText>
    <p:dataTable id="DBUsers" value="#{DBUserMBean.getDBUsers()}" var="DBUser"    
style="width: 10%">


        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="ID" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{DBUser.id}" />
        </p:column>

       <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="kolumna1" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{DBUser.kolumna1}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="kolumna2" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{DBUser.kolumna2}" />
        </p:column>

          <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="kolumna3" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{DBUser.kolumna3}" />
        </p:column>


          <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="kolumna4" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{DBUser.kolumna4}" />
        </p:column>




    </p:dataTable>
  </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the exception when I try to save something to database trough my form:

```
WARNING: /pages/index.xhtml @14,87 value="#{DBUserManagedBean.kolumna1}": 
Target Unreachable, identifier 'DBUserManagedBean' resolved to null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/index.xhtml @14,87 
value="#{DBUserManagedBean.kolumna1}": Target Unreachable, 
identifier 'DBUserManagedBean' resolved to null
```

Comment: please show the package definition for the class: public class DBUserManagedBean implements Serializable

Comment: For u Marcos Maia : package com.hibernate.maven.Hibernate_APP;  in faces-config.xml i have also :   <managed-bean-class>com.hibernate.maven.Hibernate_APP.DBUserManagedBean</managed-bean-class>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `@Table(name="your Table Name")` and also `@column` annotations.

you remove the method signature of the

```
value="#{DBUserMBean.getDBUsers()}"
```

Try this one

```
value="#{DBUserMBean.getDBUsers}"
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as my post didn't answer the question, I will only leave the comments to the author's code.

Your managed bean is declared twice, both in `faces-config.xml` and via `@ManagedBean` annotation. Though it may look like it produces ambiguity, but `faces-config.xml` takes precedence over configuration with annotations. Though, to my taste, naming beans twice, and with different names, is a way that might lead to multiple errors. So I would suggest to name the beans either with annotations, or in xml format.

Note though that `faces-config.xml` is an old-school way of defining managed beans and navigation case outcomes. JSF 2.x has support for annotations and implicit navigation.

By the way, your `@Entity` class lacks annotations for `@Column`s and `@Table`, your backing bean should either have DTO of your entity, of detached entity itself, inserting multiple fileds like you do is a bad practice and your action method should return a navigation case outcome, like `welcome`, etc.

In the end, do as @BalusC rightfully tells in comment #3, and check the fully qualified name in your xml config file and/or assure that your class file is physically present in your build.

Comment: It's not the cause of this problem. XML just overrides annotation.

Comment: @BalusC I know about precedence rules, but there is no dependency injection of the class specified in an error. What causes the problem then?

Comment: Class is just missing in classpath, exactly as exception message says. So either FQN is wrong or class file is physically absent in build. As to precedence rules, your answer didn't cover that at all and as now it turns out that you already knew it, -1 for not covering it and adding non-relevant explanation to the concrete problem (which initially implied that you didn't knew about the precedence rules at all).

Comment: I removed adnotations from DBUserManagedBean, stil got the same error. The name of packacge is :  com.hibernate.maven.Hibernate_APP; in faces-config.xml i have also : <managed-bean-class>com.hibernate.maven.Hibernate_APP.DBUserManagedBean</managed‌​-bean-class>

Comment: Try to clean the prject, then rebuild it. If the problem persists, provide us with the feedback.